# How to fix Subversion «!» status

Tags: svn

The Subversion manual states:

> '!'
>
> Item is missing (e.g. you moved or
> deleted it without using svn). This
> also indicates that a directory is
> incomplete (a checkout or update was
> interrupted).

But as so often with Subversion, there is no indication on how to fix the problem.

Normally, I would use my trusted [Fix_Subversion.command](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221005130/http://my.opera.com/krischik/blog/2010/08/02/repair-subversion) but this time it is trunk and it will take forever.

So is there any faster option?

Comment: did you move or delete the item(s) in question?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
svn revert /path/to/file
svn rm /path/to/file      # if you want to delete it from svn itself
```

Golden rule is: once something is under svn-control, any moving, deleting, renaming, should be done with svn commands (svn mv, svn rm, etc.), not using normal filesystem/file-explorer functions.

Comment: Yes I did copied and renamed. But all with svn commands and and with svn commit after each mayor change. But still things messed up.

Comment: Either _something_ did, or your svn implementation locally or on the server is broken.

Comment: I wonder if Eclipse messed things up. I do most Subversion related work on the command line. With the exceptions of package and class renaming which I do with Eclipse re-factoring. Of course Eclipse has the needed Subversion plug-in.

Comment: If there are (were) children, you may need '--depth infinity' or '--depth files' on the 'svn revert' command.

Comment: Use `svn revert -R /path/to/dir` when you want to restore a directory recursively.

Comment: in this aspect git is far better

Comment: Apparently, with current svn versions, you can just use `svn rm /path/to/file` without reverting first.

Comment: I just did a commit and the exclamation mark was replaced by a green checkmark.

Answer (score 24):

What happens after you run:

```
svn cleanup .
svn update
svn status
```

Comment: and if you're worried about time recursing into other directories, add `--depth=files` to the update

Comment: The result is:

>svn cleanup .
>svn update   
svn: REPORT of '/svnroot/uiq3/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: Secure connection truncated (https://uiq3.svn.sourceforge.net)

Doesn't look good. I guess I have to bite the bullet and recreate the whole working tree…

Answer (score 3):

I tried to revert & cleanup but it did not fix my issue. The solution I found is a bit harsh but worked:

1. rename the old_folder to new_folder.
2. from the parent issue a svn up old_folder
3. copy back the files from the new_folder [avoiding coping the .svn folder from the new_folder].

the I deleted the new_folder and in this way I managed to have a cleaned old_folder.

Comment: Which is precisely what `Fix_Subversion.command` does. But I was asking for a faster / better solution.

Besides: It might not work with Subversion 1.7 any more as Subversion 1.7 has only one .svn folder for the whole working copy.

Comment: This worked for me, on 1.6. I got the "!" after editing a file (didn't check it in) and then switching to a branch

Comment: FixSubversion.command no longer exists, so we are stuck doing it this way now.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly did you do to the branch before you received this error?

If you're having regular problems with SVN, you're probably doing something wrong (e.g. using `mv`/`rm` as opposed to `svn mv`/`svn rm` on the branch).

Comment: I copied a project to create a new similar one. I used «svn copy» to do so. I then committed the new project and started furher changes.

Comment: @Martin: So *all* you did was: `svn copy`, *make changes*, `svn commit`? If so, what were the changes? Did they involve moving, adding, or removing files?

Comment: After the commit I started the “real” work. Re-factoring packages and so on. With the next check-in the trouble started. First an update was required (strange for a one man project). That update failed and it went downhill from there.

But this was not really the question. I am used to grieve from Subversion and i just asked if there is a quick fix. 

I guess there is not so I checked out the whole tree again, copied my changes across and committed again.

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted a file and it's marked with `!`, just run `svn rm --force <filename>` to tell SVN to delete the file from the repository also.

Comment: svn status --no-ignore | grep -E '(^\!)|(^\!)' | sed -e 's/^. *//' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/' | xargs svn revert

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have committed with a message the parent folder that has the red flag, and then all the nested folders that had the icon including the parent folder are cleared.